# Tips for implementation of the spring-oauth RandomValueProviderTokenServices class

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security

I need to implement the oauth spring persistence for `RandomValueProviderTokenServices` class.
The class that needs to be stored according to the abstract protected methods of the `RandomValueProviderTokenServices` is `OAuthProviderTokenImpl`. however, this class contains a reference to `Authentication` interface which has various implementations.

I assume that implementations of these methods were done by any who used the spring-oauth library for their projects.

Is there a common practice to achieve that? ( without using the Java built it serialization mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this now and I am just storing a reference to the user in the database using their id. Then I generate the Authentication object based on that user object using this:

```
public Authentication getAuthentication(User user) {

 Object credentials = user.getUsername(); // the username of your user
    GrantedAuthority[] authorities = {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(user.getRole().getName())}; // an array of their role names

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, credentials, authorities);
    auth.setDetails(user);

    return auth;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I used the built in java serialization mechanism.